# Freeing up Serial Port properly

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm writing an app in c# that utilizes the `SerialPort` class to communicate with a few devices. Now the big problem I've been encountering all the time is how to properly free up resources there, since you immediately get an exception when trying to use a serial port that is already being used.

Since normally the GC should take care of most of the work I'm kinda out of ideas what else to try...

Mainly I tried 2 things which (in my logic) should do the work. I use session based communication, so I call an `OpenPort` and a `ClosePort` method before and after every communication - so the port should be closed. Also I've tried setting my object containing the port to null afterwards - but still I get `UnauthorizedAccessExceptions` all the time - although I am 100 percent sure that the `SerialPort.Close()` method has been called.

Do you guys know any better ways of freeing up the ports so I stop getting that exception?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers but the Dispose() stuff isn't working - I had tried that before - maybe I'm doing something wrong though so here's an example what my code looks like:

It's actually quite like Øyvind suggested, though I just added the `IDisposable` - but doesn't work either:

So this would be my wrapper class:

```
class clsRS232 : IDisposable
{
  public void clsRS232()
  {
    Serialport port = new Serialport("COM1",9600,Parity.none,8,Stopbits.one);
  }
  public void openPort()
  {
     port.Open();
  }
  public void sendfunc(string str)
  {
    port.Write(str);
  }
  public string readfunc()
  {
    port.ReadTo("\n");
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
     port.Dispose();
  }

}
```

Now whenever I need rs232 communication I call a new instance like this:

```
   clsRS232 test = new clsRS232;
   test.openport();
   test.sendfunc("test");
   test.Dispose();
```

But that doesn't change anything - I still get lots of UnauthorizedAccessExceptions - and if the other guy was right (that Dispose() of SerialPort-class only contains SerialPort.Close() ) - well then I guess I haven't really changed anything from my earlier approach, where I had a function call close();

thanks for your answers - still hoping to find the solution :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `SerialPort` implements `IDisposable`, you should write your code like this:

```
using( SerialPort port = new SerialPort( ... ) ){
  //do what you need with the serial port here
}
```

This will make sure that at the end of the `using` block, the serial port is freed, and if an exception occurs inside the `using` block it's freed to, since the `using` block is the exact same as a try/finally block, that closes/disposes the `SerialPort` inside the finally block.

**EDIT**

According to OP's needs the `SerialPort` should remain open longer than the timeframe of a method.

In that case I would wrap the entire logic that has to do with the serial port inside it's own class. In the constructor of the class, open the serial port, and write methods to do the operations you need. Then have this class implement `IDisposable` itself, and dispose the SerialPort inside your own `Dispose` method.

This will give you much better control on where you have to open and close/dispose the serial port and wrap the serial port logic into a proper class.

If you want to keep the port open for a period of time not easily contained by a block of code, then you will have to manually dispose it when you are finished with it, for example when the function that uses it gets closed or whatever triggers the release of the com port in your program.

**EDIT 2**

Your current implementation is like this:

```
clsRS232 test = new clsRS232;
test.openport();
test.sendfunc("test");
test.Dispose();
```

The problem here is that if `sendfunc` causes an exception in some way, it will never be disposed. What you gain from implementing `IDisposable` in the first place, is that you can change your code to look like this:

```
using( clsRS232 test = new clsRS232 ){
 test.openport();
 test.sendfunc("test");
}
```

Now you are guaranteed that `Dispose` will be called for your com port regardless of any exceptions inside the `using` block.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I can't really do it that way, since I have wrapped a lot of own methods in an own class, which I use for serialport communication - they all use the one port, that is initialized when the class is first called - so if I wanted to do it this way I'd end up having to write a block like this in every method that uses the port wouldn't I?

Comment: Do you want to keep the port open from the time you create the class, and close it when all operations are done, or do you want to open and close the connection to the port before and after each operation?

Comment: the first one - my wrapper class starts an instance of SerialPort via it's constructor - this then can be used via multiple methods to send/recieve, etc but once I call my own close() function ( which at the moment contains SerialPort.Close()) I want the Serialport to be completely free to be instanced again. Opening and closing ebefore and after every operation wouldn't work since for example I'd then have closed the port after writing something and open it again to recieve something -->buffer would be gone...

Comment: See my edit. I think that is a good approach for this kind of work. I did the same on a case where the serial device would send data to me on different occations, so I needed to have the port open for reading the buffer when data was received, but I needed to make sure that the port was closed in the end.

Comment: I also edited in my original post - my program was actually quite like you describe but it doens't seem to be working like that... please have a look , maybe I got you wrong in some piece...

Comment: I got it that far now - still wondering why the whole thing didn't work when calling Dispose() manually but...who cares :) just have to change a lot of my old code know since that was based on a single instance of my wrapper class per device that gets opend and closed multiple times :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very old, but I just came across the same issue and this solution worked for me, although it is a bit hacky. According to this thread [why is access to com port denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219653/why-is-access-to-com-port-denied) the issue is with a bug in the SerialPortClass. I created a wrapper class that only opens the port once, and create the class for the lifetime of the application. The SerialPort is then disposed in the Dispose of the class but is opened using the following :

```
  private SerialPort KickerPort { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
private bool OpenPort()
        {
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219653/why-is-access-to-com-port-denied
            //due to a bug in the SerialPort code, the serial port needs time to dispose if we used this recently and then closed
            //therefore the "open" could fail, so put in a loop trying for a few times
            int sleepCount = 0;
            while (!TryOpenPort())
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                sleepCount += 1;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(sleepCount.ToString());
                if (sleepCount > 50) //5 seconds should be heaps !!!
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to open kicker USB com port {0}", KickerPort.PortName));
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
     private bool TryOpenPort()
                {
                    if (!KickerPort.IsOpen)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            KickerPort.Open();
                            return true;
                        }
                        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }

                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

this is called by :

```
 try
            {
                if (OpenPort())
                {
                    //do your thing here !
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  
                throw ex;
            }
```

In my Tests ( I used it to open a cash drawer on a USB kicker) I found that sometimes it opened first time and other times it went through the sleep loop about 20 times depending on how recently the

Answer (score 1):

The implementation proposed by Øyvind Bråthen uses the IDisposable pattern in .NET. At the end of the using block, the Dispose function of the SerialPort instance is called, which will free the associated unmanaged resources (ie the serial port)

Call port.Dispose() yourself when you want to release it.

Comment: yep - had tried Dispose() before - sadly it doesn't change anything concerning my exceptions :/ Thanks though :)